# Concatenating codes to obtain sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been for tha past 2 days trying to solve this problem but can't even seem to find the right terms to google it.

I have 3 tables.

This one, with client codes that changed:

```
ActualCode=111111111  PreviousCode=44444444
```

And these two tables with value 1 and value 2:

```
PreviousCode=11111111, Value1= 50,00,  Value2= 0,00
ActualCode=44444444 ,  Value1= 0,00, Value2 = 50,00
```

I need to sum the values for each relation of Previous and Actual codes from the first table.

I.E.

For

```
ActualCode=11111111,  PreviousCode=44444444
```

I need to be able to get:

```
Code=11111111 Value1=50,00  Value2=50,00
```

Looking forward for your answer :D

Thanks,
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `join` the tables and `sum` the values:

```
select c.actualcode, 
    sum(ac.value1) + sum(pc.value1) as value1,
    sum(ac.value2) + sum(pc.value2) as value2
from codes c
    join actualcodes ac on c.actualcode = ac.actualcode
    join previouscodes pc on c.previouscode = pc.previouscode
group by c.actualcode;
```

- [Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/XXS20985)

If you could have values in the main table that don't have corresponding rows in the values tables, then you should use `outer joins` instead.

Comment: @PedroGambierLorio the best way to thank sgeddes is for you to take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers